# how controller and action name other than default one Home/Index as default?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Here **Home/Index** sets as default one along with **Url** place holders for controller/action/id.

I understand, when someone hit the browser with url (I have Home controller with Index method),

http://localhost:51712/Home/Index

then it render the view as this is set in route config.

But, if I have "Hello" controller with "Test" method and I am hitting the browser with url,

http://localhost:51712/Hello/Test

then I also got the view.

**Question, how this controller name and method name is resolved behind the scene?**

I know we have placeholders for controller/action.

Could someone below please explain this to me??

Thanks,

Comment: You may start here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you see the routes.MapRoute, controller Home and the action Index are part of the defaults parameter, but the important part to do the binding is the attribute url, the url is **url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}"**, so are saying any controller, any action and any id, for this reason the **Hello/Test** are returning the view.

The default is used when not exists any other controller and action in the URL.

Regards,